# Save document immediately after opening program

Tags: c#

Please help, I am trying to make program as soon as it opens to prompt with window to save rtf file, I try to use `Window_Activated` event but when programs starts, it does open window to save as but it doesn't matter if i press on `Save` or `Cancel`, the SaveFileDialog keeps showing up in loop and can not get pass that. This is code I used but maybe is not even good.

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        saveDlg.DefaultExt = ".rtf";
        saveDlg.Filter = "RTF Documents (.rtf)|*rtf";

        Nullable<bool> rezultat = saveDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (rezultat == true)
        {
            string filename = saveDlg.FileName;
            System.IO.File.Create(filename);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the form load event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

*> NOTE: this will used goto statement where other may argued not to

> used it but it is still supported and must only be used if no other
>   options*

```
private void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
    saveDlg.DefaultExt = ".rtf";
    saveDlg.Filter = "RTF Documents (.rtf)|*rtf";

    RetHere:
    if (saveDlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {        
        string filename = saveDlg.FileName;
        System.IO.File.Create(filename);
    }
    else {
       System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Your message here!", "Save", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK);
       goto RetHere;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jade, may I ask you in case if user press "cancel" instead of "save" I would like to have like message for user to save file, so it can not proceed further?

Comment: Where is cancel from, is that a button you created or a button from the save dialog?

Comment: I try to put your updated code, and I am getting error message on error list for "Forms" (The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the name space 'System.Windows'(are you missing and a assembly reference?).

Comment: Alright I used System.Windows.Forms SaveDialog see my update again HOPE its working now

Comment: I dont know if I am doing something wrong, but it still showing error on Forms, and I notice this before when i try to put this code in it was always showing me error.

Comment: Did you add using System.Windows.Forms in your class or pls inspect my new update.

Comment: Sorry, just to ask you when you say add System.Windows.Forms do you mean adding somewhere else except where you did in your code? I am little bit new with all this and many things dont understand. I only put in how you wrote me.

Comment: it is above your namespace on top most of your code, add this "using System.Windows.Forms;" without the double quote

Answer (score 0):

Window activated occurs when it becomes the foreground window, when you prompt the user to save, it changes focus, on clicking OK or CANCEL it changes back the focus to the main window, firing up the `Window_Activated` event. Could this be an infinite loop? I didn't test it but I guess it **could** happen.

Edit: I would suggest yout to use another event, maybe when the form loads?

Comment: Yes, I used Window_Load as Jade suggested and it work

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Window_Activated` for this (clearly). It's fired every time the window is *activated*. Here's what's happening:

1. Your app starts.
2. `Window_Activated` is executed.
3. You display the `saveDlg`, which deactivates your window.
4. The `saveDlg` closes, which activates your window.
5. Go to step #2

You need to either add a flag that is set the first time `Window_Activated` is executed, and check for it before executing the code, or use a different event that only runs once (like `Load`).